# Beginning android games, 2nd edition engine

Tags: android

I recently bought the book from Apress and have worked my way through it, unfortunately, it seems to just be dealing with side scrolling games and not Zelda-like top down games. I was wondering if anyone out there can tell me if it's possible to use their engine to create such a game?  It doesn't go into how to build a top down tile map.  Using the engine in their book, how can I make a tile map easily that has walls and things like that?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zelda gives the illusion of top down view. In all reality it's still flat just like your sidescroller. The trick is to program how entities like your player and enemies interact with these tiles. If you take away gravity and allow your character to move in 8 directions you actually have something already ( assuming your side scroller chapters handled collision already)

Comment: Does it *really matter* that you use the engine from that book? That's going to severely limit the answers you get.

Comment: It is the engine I'm using, therefore it is the one for which I need answers.  The previous comment, however, followed by the answer given has told me enough in that I can use straight Java.  I'm still not absolutely certain that the engine can do it without editing but still, it can be done.  There aren't a ton of tutorials online, however like had been said--at least I can't find them.

Comment: @Multifaceted.Abnormal In most cases the stuff you build from such books are only meant to give you applicable examples. To learn how things work ( one way that is ). It's probably time you move to a mature engine with a great community support. I assume you want to make games, not technical marvels?

Comment: I want to build a personal game.  It doesn't matter to me what engine it runs with as long as it runs.  I simply needed to know if the engine I have is capable of doing what I need it to do.  If it is, I see no reason to alter my plans to use it.  I'm fairly certain that it can.  I'm just not completely sure how to do it but those responses dealing with those things have helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android game development uses Java. Throughout the internet there are a ton of tutorials on isometric map development and top down map development.

use a 2d array, for example
private int map[][] = {{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,0,0},{1,1,1,1}};

to create a 2d data structure, assign the numeric value in the 2d array with an associated image, by looping through the 2d array and saying if the current position in the 2d array is a 1 or a 0 or any number or a character or a string or an object type (that also includes using Rectangle, for the use of defining square boundaries (useful in basic collision detection))

a top down map or an isometric map is a grid with small square images placed into position.

you could also wander about and find this post on dreamincode
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/282580-java-2d-array-tile-map-collision/